# Datadog monitor using Terraform - invalid query

Tags: terraform, monitor, datadog

I try to create a monitor using the Datadog Terraform provider.

The query that I try to use is

`query = "logs(\"\"Write lock timeout: failed to acquire lock\" source:(productA.fluentbit.sidecar OR productA-server)\").index(\"*\").rollup(\"count\").by(\"source\").last(\"5m\") > 1"`

When I run `terraform plan` I receive the error

> │ Error: error validating monitor from https://api.XXX.datadoghq.com/api/v1/monitor/validate: 400 Bad Request: {"errors":["The value provided for parameter 'query' is
> invalid"]}

Comment: Please add the entire code block to the question, not only the query.

Comment: You have an extra \" at the beginning. Not sure it that break the acceptance

Comment: This one worked for me `"query": "logs(\"\\\"Write lock timeout: failed to acquire lock\\\" source:(productA.fluentbit.sidecar OR productA-server)\").index(\"*\").rollup(\"count\").by(\"source\").last(\"5m\") > 1"`

Answer (score 0):

The issu was not in the query itself but I've tried to use

```
type: "query alert"
```

but the correct one in my case is

```
type: "log alert"
```

So, yes. @marko-e, you were right. I should provide more than just the query.

Thank you everyone for help.